# How to change a marker color based on a rule in Qgis

Tags: qgis, symbology, style

I am styling point markers in a layer that I imported using "Add Delimited Text Layer". I want the style markers based on the color marker. So each color relates to a different species (I have two different species).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Style properties of your layer. Then change the method to categorize, chose the field of "species", clic on classify and change the color you want for each classes.

[image]